# XML Schema to restrict one field based on another

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-1.0

I have the following schema, which I use to ensure that a person's `PhoneNumber` and `PhoneNumberType` (Home, Work, etc.) is not longer than 10 characters. However, I want to improve this schema so that `PhoneNumberType` is not required if a `PhoneNumber` is not provided, but is required if the `PhoneNumber` is provided. Is there a way to do this in XML Schema 1.0?

I am aware this could be accomplished in XML Schema 1.1 using `<xs:assert/>`, but unfortunately I am stuck with XML Schema 1.0.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="PhoneNumber">
    <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:minLength value="0"/>
        <xs:maxLength value="10"/>
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="PhoneNumberType">
    <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:minLength value="0"/>
        <xs:maxLength value="10"/>
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, XML Schema can't do that.

Some similar questions:

- [can the length of two xml lists be defined as being required to be equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483591/can-the-length-of-two-xml-lists-be-defined-as-being-required-to-be-equal)
- [Restrict Element Values Based on Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380260/restrict-element-values-based-on-attribute)
- [How to use attribute value as a discriminator for XML polymorphic type selection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316662/how-to-use-attribute-value-as-a-discriminator-for-xml-polymorphic-type-selection)
- [How to Validate in XSD the xml node value against it’s neighbor xml node value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206851/how-to-validate-in-xsd-the-xml-node-value-against-its-neighbor-xml-node-value)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that this is a "has" relationship.

If you have a PhoneNumber element, then it should have a property that is of type PhoneNumberType.  Rather than messing around with validating and restrictions, I would suggest that you turn PhoneNumber into a complex element and make PhoneNumberType a required property of it.

Comment: I can't change the structure of the XML document, as it comes from an external source.

Answer (score 0):

May be too late, but you can put them in group like this

```
<xs:group name="group">
<xs:sequence>
    <xs:element ref="PhoneNumber"/>
    <xs:element ref="PhoneNymberType" />
</xs:sequence>
```

And make this group required or not